# How can I detect a html element by event click without getElements...?

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

On one page, several Collapsibles can occur! I would like to now, if a link is activated. Get the ProductItem in which the link was activated.

I have tried it with getElementsByClass but get a complete Node-List which doesn't help me! Because there can be several collapsibles on one page

```
<div class="collapsible">
    <div class="collapsible__item collapsible__item--active">
        <div class="collapsible__body" style="">
            <section id="c395" class="frame centered frame-type-flux_productlistitem frame-layout-0">
                <section>
                    <div class="products">
                        <ul class="products__list">
                            <li class="products__item">
                              <p><a>Link</a></p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="products__item">
                               <p><a>Link</a></p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the JavaScript you have as well? It's hard to tell just from that markup what you're trying to do and what you've tried.

Comment: I tried a few things and it didn't work out!
I was hoping someone could give me a hint!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use event delegation, where you set up an event handler on a high level DOM element and then investigate the instigating element through the event reference:

```js
// Set up the event on a high-level element
document.querySelector(".collapsible").addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  // Get information about the element that originated the event
  console.log("The event originated with: ", evt.target);
  console.log("The product is: ", evt.target.closest("li").classList.toString());
});
```

```html
<div class="collapsible">
    <div class="collapsible__item collapsible__item--active">
        <div class="collapsible__body" style="">
            <section id="c395" class="frame centered frame-type-flux_productlistitem frame-layout-0">
                <section>
                    <div class="products">
                        <ul class="products__list">
                            <li class="products__item1">
                              <p><a>Link 1</a></p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="products__item2">
                               <p><a>Link 2</a></p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```